# Code max in a text using canvas.drawText

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have problem with drawText method of canvas.

```
int code = 259; // 'ă'

canvas.drawText((char)code + "", 0, 1, positionX, baseline, paint);
```

Why it's not working?

If `code < 256`, then OK.

Comment: You want to see the character or its order number?

Comment: I want show 'ă' character to canvas. But not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
canvas.drawText(String.valueOf((char)code), 0, 1, positionX, baseline, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
char[] c = {259}; //'ă'
canvas.drawText(new String(c) + "", 0, 1, positionX, baseline, paint);
```